# ExtJS5 CellClick events

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm new to ExtJS and trying to use Grid for displaying some data inside each tab of a tabPanel. It's done, but when I'm trying to use 'cellClick' event to trigger a 'alert' popout to display this data of whichever cell was clicked, I'm having some issue.

This is (part of) my code

```
xtype: 'tabpanel',
        items:[{
                xtype: 'grid',
                listeners: {
                    el:{
                        'cellclick' : function(view, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts){
                            alert('Testing!');
                        }
                    }
                },
                store: ***
                columns: ***
```

So few questions here:

1. Some examples don't have 'el:{}', what's this for? I have to add it otherwise it won't compile. How come others can?
2. No matter which cell I click inside this certain tab, the alert just won't be triggered. Misspelling or should I get rid of the single quote (') ?

Comment: Can you please tell, which ExtJS version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'm using ExtJS5

Comment: according to this, https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-cellclick , it should work without a problem they way you do it (though, it doesn't need the 'el')

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, the `cellclick` event is the correct one you have chosen.

Also, if I try it out on the [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/10pg), it seems to work without a problem. I took the basic example from the page and added the cell-click event

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    listeners: {
        'cellclick': function() {
            alert('hey');
        }
    },
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

The el represents a HTML element as far as I am aware, and would mean that the events are triggered on the HTML elements created by the Grid, whilst the cellclick event is rather a ExtJS event for the grid. As an example, this also works, but then suddenly a click works for the header cells where a cellclick event doesn't trigger when you click on the header cells. 
*Notice i have changed the event to **click** instead of **cellclick**, as **cellclick** is not a DOM event*

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    listeners: {
        click: {
            element: 'el',
            fn: function() {
                alert('hey');
            }
        }
    },
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

You can find more about listeners configuration option on the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-listeners) page

Btw, it's quite important to give a precise enough version of ExtJS, as there are quite some changes also within one major version (and there are different docs per subversion (eg: 5.0.1, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, ...)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!

Comment: The answer is almost correct but the question is: "What does the `el` property mean when setting `listeners` on components?"  The documentation doesn't list using `el` at the top, it lists `element` within the list: `new Ext.panel.Panel({
      title: 'The title',
      listeners: {
          click: this.handlePanelClick,
          element: 'body'
      }
  });` See http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-addListener

Comment: @JuanMendes is this not the clickrepeater that is ment with the 'el'? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.ClickRepeater

Comment: ClickRepeater has nothing do do with the listeners config, does it? `el` is not valid when setting listeners, the valid option is `element`. However, the code you posted seems to work exactly as if one had typed: `listeners: {click: function() {} , element: 'el'}`. I would stay away from the undocumented feature though (unless you can find it in the docs :)

Comment: @JuanMendes I agree, so I updated the code and added a link to a components listeners section :) I rather think/assume than using `el` is a shortcut for `element: 'el'` or that it gets handled internally like that